# Spark - Calculate total number of transitions for events

Tags: scala, apache-spark

having the following RDD:

RDD = (AAAAABAAAAABAAAAABAAAAAB, BBAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA)

I have to calculate the total number of transition between events, so for this example the result should be:

```
  ("A","B") -> 5 , ("B","A") -> 5
```

For the moment, I have the following solution but I don't know if there could be a more efficient implementation.

```
val rddSplited =  rdd.map((x) => x.split(":")(1)
.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1"))
val finalrdd =  rddSplited.flatMap(x => x.sliding(2))
.map(x => ((x.charAt(0).toString,x.charAt(1).toString),1l))
val finalmap = finalrdd.reduceByKey(_+_).collectAsMap()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some filtering and grouping can be included in "flatMap"

```
rddSplited.flatMap(row => row.sliding(2).
    filter(pair => pair(0) != pair(1)).toSeq.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
)
```

Result:

```
(BA,3)
(AB,4)
(BA,2)
(AB,1)
```